# How to pick the pre-trained weights of a network up to a certain layer using keras?

Tags: python-3.x, keras, transfer-learning

Let's suppose we want to use in our model the pre-trained weights of VGG16 up to the layer before the third max pooling and then add the layers of our choice, how could we make this happen?

[VGG16 architecture overview](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/An-overview-of-the-VGG-16-model-architecture-this-model-uses-simple-convolutional-blocks_fig2_328966158)

Answer (score 0):

You can to create a new model with say, base_model (VGG model with loaded weights and the unwanted layers 'pop()'ped). Then add VGG and other layers of your choice to the empty sequential model